# How to get rid of strongly typed tableadapters and datatables

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datatable, visual-studio-2005, tableadapter, maintainability

In our organization we are maintaining a VS 2005 website that relies heavily on strongly typed tableadapters and datatables. Needless to say that it is a maintainability nightmare for many reasons:

- To generate new table adapters we need to connect to an MSSQL2005 and less database and since we upgraded our database to MSSQL2008 this is really hell.
- We're in the end of 2010 and we really like to use VS2010 for this project but upgrading it fails to compile miserably. I guess we could work on getting this to work but we would rather get rid of this terrible technology all together.
- The generated code is huge and looks awful and I doubt anyone can understand it without something like LSD.

At this point we really would like to do the minimum to help us get rid of these tableadapters because we don't have time and it is less of a priority for management because it "works". So suggesting nHibernate is a revolution that we will not probably ensue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't offer any help. I've been there and done that (from scratch). I just wanted to say that I love this question. ADO.NET's Typed Datasets look great on the surface, but a real PITA in the long run.

Comment: I managed to build a full asp.net app based on typed datasets *and* worked with both oracle and sql server. Talk about a cluster!

Answer (score 2):

I had a VS 2005 solution with many strongly typed DataSets and TableAdapters. I upgraded it to VS 2008 a few years ago without any major issues, and I just recently upgraded it to 2010 without any major issues. I did have some problems getting my column property changes to stick after the 2010 upgrade, so I resorted to not opening any DataSets unless I absolutely had to make changes.

My advise would be to try upgrading to 2008 first, then upgrade to 2010. If that fails, perhaps its time to refactor your DAL ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a lot of compile errors when upgrading to VS2010 because the generated method signatures are different. I really would like to refactor the DAL but I don't see clear way on how to do it because I can't test my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Delucia,

I'm not sure of the kind of answer/solution you're looking for because on the one hand you say you rely heavily on typed dataset but then you want to get rid of them. :)

So I'll try and answer your question by way of providing a solution I have used in the past, so here goes.

```
    /// <summary>
///This class is a wrapper around a DataTable,
///Associated with the stored procedure - usp_GET_FEATURES
///This class provides a strongly typed interface to access data from the DataTable
///containing the result of the given stored procedure.
/// </summary>
public class FeaturesDtw : BaseDataTableWrapper
{
    public Int32 Id { get { return (Int32)DataRow[0]; } }
    public String Title { get { return (String)DataRow[1]; } }
    public String ShortDesc { get { return (String)DataRow[2]; } }
    public String Description { get { return (String)DataRow[3]; } }
    public String ImageFilePath { get { if (DataRow[4] != DBNull.Value) return (String)DataRow[4]; else return default(String); } }
    public String ImageFileName { get { if (DataRow[5] != DBNull.Value) return (String)DataRow[5]; else return default(String); } }
    public String ImageMimeType { get { if (DataRow[6] != DBNull.Value) return (String)DataRow[6]; else return default(String); } }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get { return (DateTime)DataRow[7]; } }

    public FeaturesDtw()
        :base()
    {
    }

    public FeaturesDtw(DataRow row)
        :base(row)
    {
    }
}
```

The class you see above is what I call a DataTable wrapper. Essentially it gives you the ability to work with a DataTable in a strongly types fashion in that the class is a auto generated class it's fields map directly to a table or stroed proc in your database.

You could use it in one of the following ways:

```
  var dt = DataModule.GetFeaturesDataSet().Tables[0];
  FeatureDtw featureDtw = new FeatureDtw();
  foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    featureDtw.DataRow = row;
    var id = featureDtw.Id;
    var title = featureDtw.Title;
  }
```

In the code above I get the DataTab (the variable dt) from my DAL and then I use the wrapper to get at the fields in a strongly typed manner.

OR

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableDtw<T>(DataTable dt) where T : BaseDataTableWrapper, new()
{
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    var baseDataTableWrapper = new T();
    baseDataTableWrapper.DataRow = row;
    yield return baseDataTableWrapper;
  }
}
```

you can pass the dt variable to the above method and get back an IEnumerable and you can use it like any normal IEnumerable, except that the data is really coming from a DataTable.

In both cases it is strongly typed. Of course the assumption in both cases it that you don't intend to use the DataTable to post data back but rather only to extract data out.

Hope that makes sense?

The base class is listed below

```
    /// <summary>
///This class Base Class for all DataTable Wrappers
/// </summary>
public class BaseDataTableWrapper
{
    public DataRow DataRow { get; set; }

    public BaseDataTableWrapper()
    {
    }

    public BaseDataTableWrapper(DataRow row)
        :this()
    {
        DataRow = row;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was related to the generated strongly typed datasets and datatables (and datatable adapters). So, he doesnt need a new way to make a strongly typed datatable, but to replace them with something better.